# Solving an equation involving exponential function (for optimization )

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

I have the equation

$$ c \tan \left(\theta\right)+\frac{a b A \exp \left(-b\left[\theta-a\right]\right)}{\left[1+a \exp \left(-b\left[\theta-a\right]\right)\right]^2}=0 $$

where $a,b,c$ and $A$ are constants. How can I solve this equation for $\theta$? I’d especially like to solve it equation in Matlab.

Comment: no closed-form solution for this equation; you could solve it numerically.

Comment: Following up on comment by @Carlo Beenakker have you tried fsolve ?